# node.js, windows 7, spawn chrome, can't set user-data-dir

Tags: windows, node.js, spawn

I'm trying to open Google Chrome with node.js on Windows 7 using `spawn`. It seems to work for all arguments except for setting the `user-data-dir`. However, `--user-data-dir` works directly from command line and also works if I call a .cmd file from node, passing the argument through it.

Chrome opens in the background (shows in task manager) but the browser window doesn't open and I have to manually kill the process in task manager to end it.

I get no errors or any indication of what the problem is.

Here is my node code:

```
var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;
var exe = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\application\\chrome.exe';


//this does not work and gives no errors just starts chrome in the background but fails to open browser window
// var args = [
//      '--user-data-dir=C:\\Windows\\Temp\\testingdir',
//      'http://www.google.com'
//  ];

//actual output from running this through a .cmd file and echoing out the arguments
// --user-data-dir=C:\Windows\Temp\testingdir http://www.google.com
//running the above arguments through a .cmd file from nodejs or manually running them in the cli works



//this works from nodejs, other arguments work too, just not the --user-data-dir argument
// var args = ['http://www.google.com'];

chrome = spawn(exe, args);


chrome.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

chrome.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

chrome.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  // chrome.kill();
});
```

As you can see in the commented out code it works as long as I don't try to change the user-data-dir. I've tried different temp directories and setting full access to 'everyone' on the temp directory in case it was a permissions issue.

**Update:** I just updated from v0.8.1 I think to the latest v0.8.14 and now when it fails the `on('exit', function())` actually returns a code.

```
child process exited with code 20
```

How can I look up this code to find out what it means?

**Update 2** The exit code 20 I think was just a one time fluke because I can't reproduce it any more. Trying to test different things is kinda buggy because I have to remember to kill the chrome processes in task manager each time to make sure I get the same results. So it's back to the same results as before, no errors but no chrome window, and some chrome processes running that have to be manually killed.

**Update 3**
I just moved this script over to Ubuntu and changed the exe and args to reflect the different file structure, and it works on Ubuntu.

```
exe = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
```

and

```
args = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "--user-data-dir=/home/lotus/testdir"
    ];
```

So I can confirm this is specifically related to Chrome on Windows.

Comment: In case someone finds this through google, the reason no errors show is because the code (like the example on nodejs.org) is lacking a `chrome.on('error', function () { console.log(arguments); });` event listener.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had long given up. Seems a newer version of node may have resolved the issue. I just ran this code on node 0.10.10 and it works. One other new thing is C:/some/path works but C:\\some\\path is no longer working. I'm glad for that because I hate typing those back slashes in windows. Either way it's good to know about the error event listener.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hiteksoftware.com/mize/Knowledge/articles/049.htm

`20 The system cannot find the device specified.`

doesn't make much sense though

Comment: Thank you mihai for that link. It will come in very handy as I did several google searches and couldn't find a listing like that. However, I need to edit the question because it seems that was just a one time fluke. I can't reproduce it. After killing the chrome processes and trying again, I still get the same results as before.